# how to use gcc to compile the c file which contains functions defined in another c file?

Tags: gcc, hyperlink

I have two c files named `file1.c` and `file2.c`, both including another header file, `file3.h`. I define a function inside `file2.c` and declare it in `file3.h`. Then I use the function inside `file2.c`.

The question is, how can I compile `file1.c` using gcc? I used `gcc file.c` and it shows no reference to that function. I think maybe we need some link options?

Comment: I think `gcc -o myprog file1.c file2.c` will attempt to compile and link your two files into an executable named `myprog` for you.  If you're just trying to compile a single file, without producing an executable, you would use `gcc -c file1.c` to _compile_ `file1.c`

Comment: @SteveValliere  Hi, it seems to work. The problem is that both file1.c and file2.c have a main function so that they can not be made into one executable. I just want to share some function definitions. But what do you mean by saying "without producing an executable"? I need an executable to execute the logic in file1.c.

Comment: The simplest thing would be to create another file, for example `shared.c` that contains _only_ the functions that are used by both programs (and remove those functions from `file1.c` and `file2.c`)  Then build each program separately these two commands: `gcc -oprogram1 file1.c shared.c` and `gcc -o program2 file2.c shared.c`